# linux: m3u8: how to manually download and create an mp4 from segments listed in .m3u8

Tags: linux, bash, ffmpeg, m3u8, aria2

I have an .m3u8 url i.e http://example.com/test.m3u8

I can download it by ffmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg -y -loglevel verbose -i "http://example.com/test.m3u8" -c copy -f mpegts test.mp4
```

But i am trying to do this manually:

I tried the following:

1) download the m3u8 file:

```
wget -O test.m3u8 "http://example.com/test.m3u8"
```

2) then download each segment into a folder:

```
aria2c -i test.m3u8
```

this downloads all the .ts files in the folder.

3) then i combine them

```
cat *.ts > out.ts
```

4) then i try to convert to mp4:

```
$ ffmpeg -i out.ts -c:v libx264 outputfilename.mp4
ffmpeg version 3.4.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7.3.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --disable-debug --disable-static --disable-stripping --enable-avisynth --enable-avresample --enable-fontconfig --enable-gmp --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgsm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxcb --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-shared --enable-version3 --enable-omx
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
out.ts: Invalid data found when processing input
```

I am getting the following the above error finally. `Invalid data found when processing input`. Also i heard these files are encrypted. So i am not sure about how to do this.

Below is an example .m3u8 file:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:5
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:5
#UPLYNK-SEGMENT: fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc,00000000,segment
#UPLYNK-KEY:https://content-aapm1.uplynk.com/check?b=fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc&v=fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc
#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2018-06-01T05:25:50.630000+00:00
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="https://content-aapm1.uplynk.com/check2?b=fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc&v=fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc&r=g",IV=0x00000000000000000000000000000000
#EXTINF:4.0960,
https://stgec-ausw-tmp.uplynk.com/80C078/ausw/slices/fad/10b98e7c615f43a98b180d51797e74aa/fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc/G00000000.ts?x=0&si=0
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="https://content-aapm1.uplynk.com/check2?b=fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc&v=fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc&r=g",IV=0x00000000000000000000000000000001
#EXTINF:4.0960,
https://stgec-ausw-tmp.uplynk.com/80C078/ausw/slices/fad/10b98e7c615f43a98b180d51797e74aa/fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc/G00000001.ts?x=0&si=0
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="https://content-aapm1.uplynk.com/check2?b=fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc&v=fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc&r=g",IV=0x00000000000000000000000000000002
#EXTINF:4.0960,
https://stgec-ausw-tmp.uplynk.com/80C078/ausw/slices/fad/10b98e7c615f43a98b180d51797e74aa/fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc/G00000002.ts?x=0&si=0
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="https://content-aapm1.uplynk.com/check2?b=fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc&v=fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc&r=g",IV=0x00000000000000000000000000000003
#EXTINF:4.0960,
https://stgec-ausw-tmp.uplynk.com/80C078/ausw/slices/fad/10b98e7c615f43a98b180d51797e74aa/fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc/G00000003.ts?x=0&si=0
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="https://content-aapm1.uplynk.com/check2?b=fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc&v=fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc&r=g",IV=0x00000000000000000000000000000004
#EXTINF:4.0960,
https://stgec-ausw-tmp.uplynk.com/80C078/ausw/slices/fad/10b98e7c615f43a98b180d51797e74aa/fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc/G00000004.ts?x=0&si=0
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="https://content-aapm1.uplynk.com/check2?b=fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc&v=fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc&r=g",IV=0x00000000000000000000000000000005
#EXTINF:4.0960,
https://stgec-ausw-tmp.uplynk.com/80C078/ausw/slices/fad/10b98e7c615f43a98b180d51797e74aa/fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc/G00000005.ts?x=0&si=0
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="https://content-aapm1.uplynk.com/check2?b=fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc&v=fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc&r=g",IV=0x00000000000000000000000000000006
#EXTINF:4.0960,
https://stgec-ausw-tmp.uplynk.com/80C078/ausw/slices/fad/10b98e7c615f43a98b180d51797e74aa/fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc/G00000006.ts?x=0&si=0
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="https://content-aapm1.uplynk.com/check2?b=fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc&v=fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc&r=g",IV=0x00000000000000000000000000000007
#EXTINF:4.0960,
https://stgec-ausw-tmp.uplynk.com/80C078/ausw/slices/fad/10b98e7c615f43a98b180d51797e74aa/fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc/G00000007.ts?x=0&si=0
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="https://content-aapm1.uplynk.com/check2?b=fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc&v=fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc&r=g",IV=0x00000000000000000000000000000008
#EXTINF:4.0960,
https://stgec-ausw-tmp.uplynk.com/80C078/ausw/slices/fad/10b98e7c615f43a98b180d51797e74aa/fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc/G00000008.ts?x=0&si=0
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="https://content-aapm1.uplynk.com/check2?b=fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc&v=fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc&r=g",IV=0x00000000000000000000000000000009
#EXTINF:4.0960,
https://stgec-ausw-tmp.uplynk.com/80C078/ausw/slices/fad/10b98e7c615f43a98b180d51797e74aa/fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc/G00000009.ts?x=0&si=0
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="https://content-aapm1.uplynk.com/check2?b=fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc&v=fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc&r=g",IV=0x0000000000000000000000000000000A
#EXTINF:4.0960,
https://stgec-ausw-tmp.uplynk.com/80C078/ausw/slices/fad/10b98e7c615f43a98b180d51797e74aa/fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc/G0000000A.ts?x=0&si=0
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="https://content-aapm1.uplynk.com/check2?b=fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc&v=fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc&r=g",IV=0x0000000000000000000000000000000B
#EXTINF:4.0960,
https://stgec-ausw-tmp.uplynk.com/80C078/ausw/slices/fad/10b98e7c615f43a98b180d51797e74aa/fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc/G0000000B.ts?x=0&si=0
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="https://content-aapm1.uplynk.com/check2?b=fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc&v=fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc&r=g",IV=0x0000000000000000000000000000000C
#EXTINF:4.0960,
https://stgec-ausw-tmp.uplynk.com/80C078/ausw/slices/fad/10b98e7c615f43a98b180d51797e74aa/fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc/G0000000C.ts?x=0&si=0
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="https://content-aapm1.uplynk.com/check2?b=fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc&v=fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc&r=g",IV=0x0000000000000000000000000000000D
#EXTINF:4.0960,
https://stgec-ausw-tmp.uplynk.com/80C078/ausw/slices/fad/10b98e7c615f43a98b180d51797e74aa/fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc/G0000000D.ts?x=0&si=0
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="https://content-aapm1.uplynk.com/check2?b=fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc&v=fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc&r=g",IV=0x0000000000000000000000000000000E
#EXTINF:4.0960,
https://stgec-ausw-tmp.uplynk.com/80C078/ausw/slices/fad/10b98e7c615f43a98b180d51797e74aa/fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc/G0000000E.ts?x=0&si=0
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="https://content-aapm1.uplynk.com/check2?b=fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc&v=fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc&r=g",IV=0x0000000000000000000000000000000F
#EXTINF:4.0960,
https://stgec-ausw-tmp.uplynk.com/80C078/ausw/slices/fad/10b98e7c615f43a98b180d51797e74aa/fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc/G0000000F.ts?x=0&si=0
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="https://content-aapm1.uplynk.com/check2?b=fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc&v=fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc&r=g",IV=0x00000000000000000000000000000010
#EXTINF:4.0960,
https://stgec-ausw-tmp.uplynk.com/80C078/ausw/slices/fad/10b98e7c615f43a98b180d51797e74aa/fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc/G00000010.ts?x=0&si=0
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="https://content-aapm1.uplynk.com/check2?b=fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc&v=fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc&r=g",IV=0x00000000000000000000000000000011
#EXTINF:4.0960,
https://stgec-ausw-tmp.uplynk.com/80C078/ausw/slices/fad/10b98e7c615f43a98b180d51797e74aa/fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc/G00000011.ts?x=0&si=0
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="https://content-aapm1.uplynk.com/check2?b=fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc&v=fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc&r=g",IV=0x00000000000000000000000000000012
#EXTINF:4.0960,
https://stgec-ausw-tmp.uplynk.com/80C078/ausw/slices/fad/10b98e7c615f43a98b180d51797e74aa/fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc/G00000012.ts?x=0&si=0
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="https://content-aapm1.uplynk.com/check2?b=fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc&v=fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc&r=g",IV=0x00000000000000000000000000000013
#EXTINF:4.0960,
https://stgec-ausw-tmp.uplynk.com/80C078/ausw/slices/fad/10b98e7c615f43a98b180d51797e74aa/fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc/G00000013.ts?x=0&si=0
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="https://content-aapm1.uplynk.com/check2?b=fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc&v=fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc&r=g",IV=0x00000000000000000000000000000014
#EXTINF:4.0960,
https://stgec-ausw-tmp.uplynk.com/80C078/ausw/slices/fad/10b98e7c615f43a98b180d51797e74aa/fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc/G00000014.ts?x=0&si=0
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="https://content-aapm1.uplynk.com/check2?b=fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc&v=fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc&r=g",IV=0x00000000000000000000000000000015
#EXTINF:4.0960,
https://stgec-ausw-tmp.uplynk.com/80C078/ausw/slices/fad/10b98e7c615f43a98b180d51797e74aa/fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc/G00000015.ts?x=0&si=0
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="https://content-aapm1.uplynk.com/check2?b=fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc&v=fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc&r=g",IV=0x00000000000000000000000000000016
#EXTINF:4.0960,
https://stgec-ausw-tmp.uplynk.com/80C078/ausw/slices/fad/10b98e7c615f43a98b180d51797e74aa/fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc/G00000016.ts?x=0&si=0
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="https://content-aapm1.uplynk.com/check2?b=fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc&v=fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc&r=g",IV=0x00000000000000000000000000000017
#EXTINF:4.0960,
https://stgec-ausw-tmp.uplynk.com/80C078/ausw/slices/fad/10b98e7c615f43a98b180d51797e74aa/fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc/G00000017.ts?x=0&si=0
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="https://content-aapm1.uplynk.com/check2?b=fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc&v=fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc&r=g",IV=0x00000000000000000000000000000018
#EXTINF:4.0960,
https://stgec-ausw-tmp.uplynk.com/80C078/ausw/slices/fad/10b98e7c615f43a98b180d51797e74aa/fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc/G00000018.ts?x=0&si=0
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="https://content-aapm1.uplynk.com/check2?b=fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc&v=fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc&r=g",IV=0x00000000000000000000000000000019
#EXTINF:4.0960,
https://stgec-ausw-tmp.uplynk.com/80C078/ausw/slices/fad/10b98e7c615f43a98b180d51797e74aa/fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc/G00000019.ts?x=0&si=0
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="https://content-aapm1.uplynk.com/check2?b=fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc&v=fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc&r=g",IV=0x0000000000000000000000000000001A
#EXTINF:4.0960,
https://stgec-ausw-tmp.uplynk.com/80C078/ausw/slices/fad/10b98e7c615f43a98b180d51797e74aa/fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc/G0000001A.ts?x=0&si=0
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="https://content-aapm1.uplynk.com/check2?b=fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc&v=fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc&r=g",IV=0x0000000000000000000000000000001B
#EXTINF:4.0960,
https://stgec-ausw-tmp.uplynk.com/80C078/ausw/slices/fad/10b98e7c615f43a98b180d51797e74aa/fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc/G0000001B.ts?x=0&si=0
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="https://content-aapm1.uplynk.com/check2?b=fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc&v=fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc&r=g",IV=0x0000000000000000000000000000001C
#EXTINF:3.6405,
https://stgec-ausw-tmp.uplynk.com/80C078/ausw/slices/fad/10b98e7c615f43a98b180d51797e74aa/fadd0d418aea4c5da8b87feec9b0acbc/G0000001C.ts?x=0&si=0
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

Comment: I'm don't know much about ts files, but I have the feeling that `cat *.ts` won't create a proper ts file, similar to how `cat *.pdf` won't create a proper pdf file. Try to concat your files using `ffmpeg`.

Comment: Concatinating ts segments IS correct.

Comment: You must decrypt before you concatinate.

Comment: how to decrypt .ts files.

Comment: Question: what about subtitles?  The source webpage I'm streaming the m3u8 from has subtitles and I'd like to include those in the file I am saving so I can choose to display them or not in VLC at a later time.  How do I include them in this command?  @SanthoshYedidi DeCSS?

Comment: @Santhosh If video is downloaded with `fmpg` command that you specified it is of a really low quality. How could the quality be increased?

Answer (score 16):

You can use youtube-dl for this:

```
youtube-dl --list-formats M3U8_URL
youtube-dl -f FORMAT_CODE --hls-prefer-native M3U8_URL
```

The names in capital letters are placeholders. `M3U8_URL` is the URL of the m3u8 file. Available `FORMAT_CODE`s are shown in the left column of output of the first command.

Comment: This should be the selected answer for being the most painless -- it worked like a dream! I successfully downloaded a video streamed by Boxcast on a site, including the signed keys, etc. on the query params (don't forget to wrap the URL in quotes!). This was on a video that was still streaming live. `youtube-dl` captured what had already been streamed.

Answer (score 6):

ffmpeg download .m3u8 and merge file.

```
fmpeg -i "http://example.com/test.m3u8" -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc output.mp4
```

ffmpeg version

```
ffmpeg -h
```

ffmpeg version 4.4.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04)
configuration: --enable-pic --disable-doc --enable-debug --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-asm --enable-x86asm --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-ffmpeg --enable-ffplay --enable-ffprobe --enable-avcodec --enable-avdevice --enable-avformat --enable-avfilter --enable-postproc --enable-swresample --enable-swscale --enable-avresample --enable-libaom --enable-libass --disable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-libdav1d --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-iconv --enable-libilbc --enable-lzma --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmodplug --enable-cuda --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-openssl --enable-libopus --enable-sdl2 --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --disable-libssh --disable-libtensorflow --disable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --disable-libxml2 --enable-zlib --pkg-config-flags=--static

Answer (score 4):

use [yt-dlp](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp)

```bash
yt-dlp your-url-to-m3u8
```

it just works.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the `cat` issue. Are you accounting for the BOM?
All .ts files start with a BOM, so if you cat them, they will break.

According to specification you can find all required encryption details in the media playlist itself.

Example line:

```
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="http://example.com/path/to/resource.mp4/crypt.key?id=somekey"
```

This contains the encryption algorithm and the uri to the key.
The encryption can be per list or per track. In your case it is per track.

Side note:
I wrote a bit about my experiences with m3u8 / ts. Maybe it can help you or give you some new idea: https://andreasvolkmann.github.io/posts/2018-04-27-m3u8-and-ts-segments/